# Use Jolt to flatten an array of objects which contain array

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

Can Jolt flatten an array of objects which contain array? For example, is there a way to write Jolt transformation specs for the following input and output?

Jolt https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt

**Input:**

```
[
  {"Id": "111", ["mobile": "1111", "home": "1112"]},
  {"Id": "222", ["mobile": "2221"]}
]
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {"Id": "111", "mobile": "1111"},
  {"Id": "111", "home": "1112"},
  {"Id": "222", "mobile": "2221"}
]
```

I didn't find a way to represent the output array indexes.

Comment: Yours Input data is incorrect. Validate it on http://jolt-demo.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

assuming input is fixed as

```
[
  {
    "Id": "111",
    "Val": [
      {
        "mobile": "1111"
      },
      {
        "home": "1112"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "222",
    "Val": [
      {
        "mobile": "2221"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

then applying the following transformation

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Id": null,
        "Val": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&3].[&0]",
            "@(2,Id)": "[&3].[&0].id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

reach the expected output:

```
[ {
  "mobile" : "1111",
  "id" : "111"
}, {
  "home" : "1112",
  "id" : "111"
}, {
  "mobile" : "2221",
  "id" : "222"
} ]
```